# Run Vim with own parameter

Tags: vim

I want to define new shortcuts in .vimrc file, but I want to use those shortcuts in special situations. Is it possible to run Vim with own parameter from cmd line and check if Vim was launched with this parameter in .vimrc file. Something like below?

```
$vim -own_param
```

In .vimrc

```
if (launched with own_param) do
    :map <F2> ...
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you give an example of these situations? Why not define these things from vimrc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot customize the command-line arguments (those are compiled-in), but you can pass arbitrary config variables via `--cmd "let g:ownParam = 'foo'"` (also multiple times). If you need to evaluate those in your `~/.vimrc` or plugins, it has to be `--cmd`, not `-c`, because the latter is only evaluated *after* that.

Another option is environment variables, whose values can be queried via `$VARNAME` in Vimscript, e.g. `$ OWNPARAM=foo vim`

#### Evaluation

```
if exists('g:own_param') && g:own_param == 'foo'
    :map <F2> ...
endif
```

Comment: I have tried it but it does not work. Error message is E121: Undefined variable: g:own_param
E15: Invalid expression: g:own_param == 'foo'

Comment: Sorry, it works. I have not noticed that names of var are different. But if I run gvim without this parameter, it writes error message. It is not disturbing, but is there any way how to suppress it?

Comment: Yes, that can be handled, see my edit. And please accept the answer by clicking on the outlined checkmark next to it!